# The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" has not been registered. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7403)

Tags: sql-server

The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" has not been registered. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7403)

when iam trying to test connection in my linked servers iam getting this error

Comment: Just install it or use another provider

Comment: How can i use another provider here

Comment: Here = where? Where do you want to use it?  On the server side you can enlist your providers like this: exec sp_enum_oledb_providers

Comment: Provider Name

SQLOLEDB
ADsDSOObject
SSISOLEDB
MSDASQL
MSOLAP
MSDAOSP

Comment: SqlOledb is there in my sql instance
 still iam getting error

Comment: Where do you try to use this provider? SQLOLEDB provider <> SQLNCLI11

Comment: I have been linked some servers to my sql server ,

Comment: Post here your linked server definition (script it as sp_addlinkedserver)

Comment: I have been linked some servers to my sql server ,
when i was trying to test connection in linked servers ,iam getting this error 7403

Comment: Already linked servers are added to my sql server ,now iam trying to test connection iam getting error 7403

Comment: Your linked server definition is not valid, this means even if the server is created it does not automatically means that the definition is correct. And if you won't post here your linked server definition (where you DO use the provider you do not have) I cannot help you

Comment: How can i know the defination for exsiting linked server ????

Comment: Right click on your linked server -> Script linked server as -> Create to -> New query window

Comment: No. EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver ....

Comment: Stop to post the options please

Comment: All I need is EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver with all the parameters

Comment: EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'A-----------11', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

Comment: With ALL the parameters

Comment: Just update your original post

Comment: EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'servername', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

Comment: i have these two options that's it

Comment: That looks fine. Are you sure you've scripted the right server?

Comment: yes , i scripted for right server ,
iam getting error 7403 for all linked servers which are linked with my sql server

Comment: Was this server upgraded from an earlier version?

Comment: yes server was upgraded from 2014 to 2016

Answer (score 3):

For one reason or for another, SQLNCLI11 is not installed on your server.

Follow these instructions [Installing SQL Server Native Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321(v=sql.110).aspx) and just install it

For 2016 check this one: [Installing SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/installing-sql-server-native-client)